# Creating a subscript of a subscript

Tags: html, css

I want to write an expression so that the is the main item, R, followed by a subscript, say 2, followed by a subscript of that 2, say 3. I can do the first two bits, `R<sub>2</sub>`, but I do not know how to make the "sub-subscript". Help would be appreciated.

I am a css coding dunce.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: As I said, I'm a css coding dunce. I had not realised that it was possible to do 'nesting' (new vocabulary for me), nor how it would be done.

But, MilesZew, what you have suggested works just fine, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find it as easy as adding a nested subscript, like so:

```html
R<sub>2<sub>3<sub>etc.</sub></sub></sub>
```